# How to use NSClickGestureRecogniser with Swift in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, click, gestures

I have attached the `NSClickGestrueRecogniser` with the storyboard and then connected an `@IBaction` to the ViewController so my understanding is that this connects the view to the view controller allowing the controller to know when the click occurs.

My aim is to have the controller perform a function when the user clicks anywhere inside the whole view.

Below is the set up of my class

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit
import Foundation
import AppKit

class SecondViewController: NSViewController, NSGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!

    @IBAction func clickG(gesture: NSClickGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state  {
        case .Changed: fallthrough
        case .Ended:
            println("Clicked")
            if webView.mainFrameURL.rangeOfString("url") == nil {
                println(webView.mainFrameURL)
            } else {
                println("Success = \(webView.mainFrameURL)")
            }
        default:
            println("Unknown")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.

        let urlString = "www.google.com"
        let urltest = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: urltest))
    }

}
```

I also set up the webView but I want to know when someone clicks inside the webView or the actual view.

Answer (score 1):

It is not too hard to do. Just declare a NSClickGestureRecognizer
instance. Then pass selector like; Selector("buttonGesture:") and attach gesture recognizer.

Then you can simply create a function to handle "buttonGesture" event. Your handler gives gesture object as view.

> More information:
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSClickGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I am going to edit my question above so make it more specific as I am not entirely sure I completely understand your answer and so will try and be more specific with my question. Thank you for your help.